# Using another function's output within the same class

Tags: python, object

I have a class where the only input is a dataframe. The first function within the class adds columns to the dataframe to create a new dataframe. I want subsequent functions within the class to use the new dataframe.

```
class House:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def df_manip(self):
        # add additional columns to the dataframe
        return new_df

    def function1(self):
        answer = new_df.column3.sum()
        return answer 

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

house_1 = House(df)
print(house_1.function1())
```

Comment: In `df_manip` add `self.df = new_df` - then use `self.df` throughout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either make a new attribute in `df_manip` or just call `df_manip` and use its return value

```
class House:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        # call to make or change attribute
        self.df_manip()

    def df_manip(self):
        # add additional columns to the dataframe 

        # make or change an attribute 
        #self.otherdf = new_df
        #self.df = new_df

        return new_df

    def function1(self):
        answer = new_df.column3.sum()

        # Use  modified attribute
        #answer = self.df.column3.sum()

        # Use df_manip return value
        #newdf = self.df_manip()
        #answer = newdf.column3.sum()

        return answer
```